# Getting a Parsing error on a template string with ESLint, but I have ECMA 6 in config file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, backticks, template-strings

I can post my whole config and JavaScript file if needed, but I am trying to run ESLint on some JavaScript I'm writing.
My 'eslintrc.json' file has this in the config (with some other rules):

```
"rules": 
{
  // Thought this was my issue and hoped it would solve it.
  "env": 
  { 
    "es6": true 
  },

  "prefer-template": "error", //template literals

  "quotes": 
  [
    "error", 
    "double", 
    { "avoidEscape": true, "allowTemplateLiterals": true }
  ]
}
```

Here is the error code that spits out in the .log file for ESLint, and the code it is failing at.

```
Parsing error: Unexpected character '`' FolderName\FileName.js:31:17
function Something()
{
  // Seperated to try and debug the issue.
  var message = `Starting Something: ${ arguments.callee.name}`;
  //            ^
  Log.Message(message);

  SomeOtherFile.UpdateEnvironmentVariables();
 }
```

I know by default ESLint uses ECMAScript 5 ([Specifying Parser Options](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options)) so I tried setting it to ECMA 6 (that has template strings - See above config file), but that didn't seem to help.

What's weird is that the ESLint documentation ([rule : quotes](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes)) explains backticks and mentions that it is only in ECMAScript 6, etc.. But it seems like the parser that ESLint uses ([Espree](https://github.com/eslint/espree) - [On ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser)) is having an issue or something.

I really don't want to go through and replace all of these with some string concatenations, any suggestions?

Comment: You need to set parser options too...

Comment: If the 'parserOptions' change you are referring to is the 'ecmaVersion' that is set by default with the env setting. ("es6 - enable all ECMAScript 6 features except for modules (this automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 6).") I also tried a few other parserOption changes and they didn't work. I can update the post when I get home

Comment: I tried

'
"parserOptions": 
{
  "ecmaVersion": 6,
  "ecmaFeatures": 
  {
     "jsx": true
  }
}
'
with the "env" set to "es6" : true, and it still has a parse error

Comment: I should read the comments before answering! ;^D Where did you set parseroptions? In eslintrc or the file? I think they *have* to be in eslintrc.

Answer (score 3):

Your code [lints as written on eslint.org/demo](https://eslint.org/demo#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%5D) when ECMA Version 2015 is set. Well, there are errors, but they aren't the template literal usage.

What this tells me is that you're running into a **parsing** error, not a **linting** error and need to set your parser settings.

#### Parsing error when ECMA Version set to 5

[image: parsing error when ECMA Version set to 5]

---

#### Parse is fine and you have LINTING errors when ECMA is 2015

[image: Parse is fine and you have LINTING errors when ECMA is 2015]

---

### Solution

To fix this, I think you *have* to provide an .eslintrc file somewhere that sets parser options to es2015 or later.

Double-check and try changing what's in yours to include this:

```
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
        "sourceType": "script",
        "ecmaFeatures": {}
    }
```

So even if your file includes the comment at the top...

```
/*eslint-env es6 */
```

... the **parser** options will win out and kill the template literal. And, as you show, your error is a *parsing* error, not a linting one:

`` Parsing error: Unexpected character '`' FolderName\FileName.js:31:17 ``

I will readily admit that's a very confusing distinction. I didn't figure it out until banging my head on this answer for a while, but it explains why my env settings in my files don't always seem to "take"; the parser options override them.

Answer (score 0):

In .eslintrc.json, I used babel-eslint and installed babel-eslint as devDependency in package.json. Hope that works for you too

.eslintrc.json file

```
{
  "env": {...},
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {...}
}
```

**Edit 1:**

babel-eslint is archived and it is suggested to use @babel/eslint-parser.
More info below

[babel eslint](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint#note-babel-eslint-is-now-babeleslint-parser-and-has-moved-into-the-babel-monorepo)

[@babel/eslint-parser](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser#usage)

```
{
   "env": {...},
   "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
   "parserOptions": {...}
}
```

**Edit 2:**

@babel/eslint-parser needs @babel-core installed. If you are not already using @babel, then its best to upgrade your eslint to 7.5 and above. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61628947/eslint-optional-chaining-error-with-vscode) to similar question: