# eslint - Optional chaining error with vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am seeing a a red underline when I'm using an optional chain, but the code runs fine as I am on node 14

Here's my setup:

```
node 14.1.0
eslint "^6.8.0"
```

.eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaVersion": 2020
    },
    "rules": {
    },
}
```

[image]

Comment: if you place the cursor over the error what error message do you get?

Comment: @peprumo `Parsing Error: Unexpected token .` added image

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You no longer need `@babel/eslint-parser` as `eslint@^7.5` now supports optional chaining.

Run the following to update eslint within your project:

#### npm

```
npm install --save-dev eslint@^7.5
```

#### yarn

```
yarn add -D eslint@^7.5
```

And then, ensure your config is as follows:

#### .eslintrc

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020
  }
}
```

#### .eslint.js

```
module.exports = {
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2020
    }
}
```

See https://eslint.org/blog/2020/07/eslint-v7.5.0-released#optional-chaining-support for more information.

Comment: This is the correct most up to date answer as of 2020

Answer (score 49):

You should use [`@babel/eslint-parser`](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser) (formerly called `babel-eslint`) with your eslint config. This allows you to lint ALL valid Babel code with eslint. [eslint supports all ES2020 features as of version v7.2.0](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/13196)

```
$ npm install @babel/eslint-parser --save-dev
# or
$ yarn add @babel/eslint-parser -D
```

Then in your `.eslintrc` do:

```
{
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
}
```

Comment: is optional chaining not included in normal eslint?

Comment: @A.Lau not that I am aware of

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet.
There's a draft on supporting some of the es2020 syntax features, optional-chaining is one of them.
You can read it here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/13196

Comment: where does that parser key go? `package.json` under "eslintConfig"?

Comment: @bot19 try putting it at the root of eslintrc config [here](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint#setup) its in `.eslintrc.js`

Comment: As @steadweb's answer says, eslint@^7.5 now supports optional chaining without @babel/eslint-parser.

Answer (score 12):

All versions of Node.js above 12 support the optional-chaining operator (a ECMAScript 2020 feature). Try to use this:

```json
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020
}
```

Answer (score 7):

First, you should have a ESLint parser that supports the optional chaining:

`npm install -D @babel/eslint-parser`

If you're facing issues with peer dependencies then run by appending `--legacy-peer-deps` to the command.

Then, you should have the ESLint version that supports the optional chaining. [This](https://eslint.org/blog/2020/07/eslint-v7.5.0-released#optional-chaining-support) is that release version(7.5.0):

`npm install eslint@^7.5`

Tell your ESLint server to use the above-installed parser:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all JavaScript features enabled by Babel are included in ESLint.

You can use [babel-eslint](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser) though:

```
$ npm install @babel/eslint-parser --save-dev
# or
$ yarn add @babel/eslint-parser -D
```

Then in your `.eslintrc` do:

```
{
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you were using `babel-eslint` (it's been deprecated sincce 2021), upgrade it to `@babel/eslint-parser` and make sure you have `eslint` version 7 or above.

In `.eslintrc.json` you need the following configuration:

```json
    "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "requireConfigFile": false,
        "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            "@babel/preset-react"
        ],
        "babelOptions": {
            "parserOpts": {
                "plugins": [ "jsx" ]
            }
        }
    },
    "plugins": [
        "prettier",
        "react-hooks"
    ],
```

`"requireConfigFile": false,` - if you don't have a eslint config file
`"plugins": [ "jsx" ]` - if you use jsx

`"plugins": [ "typescript" ]` - if you use typescript

`"plugins": [ "flow" ]` - if you use flow

Answer (score 0):

Add the override on eslint.js worked for me:

```
overrides: [
 {
  files: ['/src/**/*.jsx'],
  rules: {
   'no-unsafe-optional-chaining': ['off'],
  },
 },
],
rules: {
.....
}
```