# Fix do expression throwing linter error in VS Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have been trying for some time now to get Visual Studio Code to stop complaining and slowing down my editor with this linter error about a do expression not having a while or expecting an expression.

Here is what I'm seeing in my editor

[image]

I have eslint installed and here are the versions I have

```
"@babel/core": "7.9.0",
"babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
"@babel/eslint-plugin": "^7.12.1",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.8.3",
"eslint": "^6.6.0",
```

Here is a bit of my config

```
...
"plugins": [
  ...
  "@babel"
],
...
"rules": {
  "no-unused-expressions": 0,
  "@babel/no-unused-expressions": 2,
},
...
```

I can't figure out why I'm still getting these errors in the editor, I'm not sure if it's related to eslint at this point or if there is something else causing it be cause now when I hover over it I see this, which seems like typescript is maybe linting it now? Even though it's a javascript file?

[image]

Here is an example from the babel plugin proposal page
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-do-expressions

```
const Component = props =>
  <div className='myComponent'>
    {do {
      if(color === 'blue') { <BlueComponent/>; }
      else if(color === 'red') { <RedComponent/>; }
      else if(color === 'green') { <GreenComponent/>; }
    }}
  </div>
;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 20/11/2020**
NOTE: `babel-eslint` is now `@babel/eslint-parser` and has moved into the [Babel monorepo](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/eslint/babel-eslint-parser).

```
$ npm install @babel/eslint-parser --save-dev
# or
$ yarn add @babel/eslint-parser -D
```

Then in your `.eslintrc` do:

```
{
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
}
```

Sources:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61629494/13859552
https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring